# Jquery Checkbox remains check on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a checkbox that needs to remain check once user click on the input box.

**Issue:** On First Click the checkbox is checked, which works fine. When input is clicked again, the checkbox becomes unchecked.

**Output Needed:**

I want the checkbox to stay checked as this triggers a change event.

I have searched many examples to find this solution but could not find it.

Any help is appreciated.

**Please See Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/nrYec/194/

JS:

```
$('input').click(function() {
     $('#x').text(this.checked ? "is checked" : "is not checked");
 });
 $('.b2').click(function() {
      $('.trigger').click();
 });
```

Comment: Are you saying that clicking into either text box should set the checkbox to checked if it isn't already, but clicking on the checkbox itself should allow unchecking?

Comment: So when you click on the textboxes, why are you toggling the checkbox state? What exactly is supposed to be happening here.

Comment: @nnnnnn that is correct clicking the textbox should only work in one direction, keep the checkbox checked. unless its manually unchecked by user.

Comment: instead of clicking  the input set it to be checked. You do that with prop()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('.b2').click(function() {
    if (!$('.trigger').prop('checked')) {
        $('.trigger').prop('checked', 'true');
    };
});

$('input').click(function() {
    $('#x').text($('.trigger').prop('checked') ? "is checked" : "is not checked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class='trigger' type='checkbox'>
<input class='b2' type='text' name='something'>
<input class='b2' type='text' name='something'>
<div id='x'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You clarified in the comments that you want a click into the text boxes to check the checkbox, but for clicks on the checkbox itself to work normally. So don't trigger a click event, just directly set the checkbox's `checked` property:

```js
$('.b2').click(function() {
  $('.trigger').prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='trigger' type='checkbox'>
<input class='b2' type='text' name='something'>
<input class='b2' type='text' name='something'>
<div id='x'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to wrap it in an `if` statement:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrYec/197/)

```
$('.b2').click(function() {
  var trigger = $('.trigger');
  if (!$('.trigger').is(':checked')) {
    trigger.click();
  }
});

$('input').click(function() {
  // And need to check if the checkbox (not any input) is checked here
  $('#x').text($('.trigger').is(':checked') ? "is checked" : "is not checked"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('type') !== "checkbox")
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true)
});
```

This will force the checkbox to be checked when any other input is clicked, but behave normally when it is clicked.

Comment: but that would keep you from unchecking the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remain your checkbox checked is to add a handler onchange listener on your checkbox and just set it javascript attribute checked = true

```
$('.trigger').on('change', function() {
 $('.trigger')[0].checked = true;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

document ref: [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
$('.b2').on('click',function() {
  $('.trigger').prop("checked", true);
}).on('blur',function(){
   if($(this).val().trim().length === 0){
     $('.trigger').prop("checked", false);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='trigger' type='checkbox'>
<input class='b2' type='text' name='something'>
<input class='b2' type='text' name='something'>
<div id='x'></div>
```